# Wronskian and differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Given the fact that solutions $Y_1(t) = (x_1(t), y_1(t))$ and $Y_2(t) = (x_2(t), y_2(t))$ for the system of $\frac{dy}{dt} = AY$, where

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\
 c&d
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and then clearly the Wronskian is defined as $$W(t)= x_1(t)y_2(t)-x_2(t)y_1(t)~, $$then

1. When asked to compute $\frac{dW}{dt}$, does it equal $AW$, i.e. the matrix about multiplied by $$x_1(t)y_2(t)-x_2(t)y_1(t)~?$$
2. If $Y_1(t)$ and $Y_2(t)$ are solutions to a linear system, how do I show that $$\frac{dW}{dt} = (a+d)(W(t))~?$$
3. How do I find the general solution of the above differential equation? i.e. how do I go about figuring the determinant of this linear system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** use the multilinearity of the determinant.

details:
$$
W(t)=\begin{vmatrix}
  x_1(t) & x_2(t)\\
 y_1(t)& y_2(t)
 \end{vmatrix}\\
W'(t)=\begin{vmatrix}
  x'_1(t) & x_2(t)\\
 y'_1(t)& y_2(t)
 \end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
  x_1(t) & x'_2(t)\\
 y_1(t)& y'_2(t)
 \end{vmatrix}
\\=
\begin{vmatrix}
 ax_1(t) + bx_2(t) & x_2(t)\\
 ay_1(t) + by_2(t) & y_2(t)
 \end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
  x_1(t) & cx_1(t) + dx_2(t)\\
 y_1(t)& cy_1(t) + dy_2(t)
 \end{vmatrix}
\\=
\begin{vmatrix}
 ax_1(t)   & x_2(t)\\
 ay_1(t)  & y_2(t)
 \end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
  x_1(t) & dx_2(t)\\
 y_1(t)&  dy_2(t)
 \end{vmatrix}=(a+d)W(t)
$$

You conclude that 
$$
W(t) = [x_1(0)y_2(0) - x_2(0)y_1(0)]\exp((a+d)t)
$$